# javascript, can a variable be a value and also a function?

Tags: javascript, currying

It is possible to code in javascript like the following:

```
var foo = function(n) { //magic codes };
var bar = foo(2);

bar + 2      // result: 4
bar(2)       // result: 4
bar(2)(2)    // result: 6
```

Comment: for `bar + 2 = 4`, you'd have to overwrite `bar.toString` so it returns `2`, but doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: You kinda can, check out this article http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable can only hold one value. That value can be a function.

An object can have a `toString()` method which could be hacked to get close to what you are trying to do.

```js
function myFactory(value) {
  function myFunction(add) {
    return myFactory(value + add);
  }
  myFunction.toString = function() {
    return value;
  };
  return myFunction;
}

var bar = myFactory(2);

console.log(bar + 2);
console.log(bar(2));
console.log(bar(2)(2));
```

This is, of course, horrible.

Answer (score 2):

Currying can be done in Javascript, by returning a function.
By default variables can either be values (literal, or results of functions), or function declarations.

```js
    function add(number) {
      return function(number2) {
        return number + number2;
      }
    }

    console.log(add(5)(6));
```

There are ways to achieve what you described `bar + 2`, but that's unconventional, and in my opinion, you shouldn't use them in Javascript.

Comment: `add + 2` won't give `4` as the question is asking with that code.

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired by Quetin's answer and found the [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) property

```js
var foo = function(n) {
  var fn = function(x) {
    return foo(n + x);
  };

  fn.valueOf = function() {
    return n;
  };

  return fn;
}

var bar = foo(2);

console.log(bar + 2 === 4, bar);
console.log(bar(2) === 4, bar(2));
console.log(bar(2)(2) === 6, bar(2)(2));
```

I admit the log results does come out strange but it works as intended.